# Nginx - turn an $arg_ into a path with 3 subdirectories for try_files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm currently working on an image caching server using **Nginx**, however I'm running into *problems getting Nginx to serve the cached images*.

There are two kinds of images the caching server is supposed to be able to serve, the *first being rather small images* which require little interference from the image server.

This works the way I want it to using the following configuration:

```
location = /small/ {
  try_files /small/logos/$arg_id.jpg @gen_script;
}
location @gen_script {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /small/index.php?id=$arg_id;
}
```

No problems here, using this configuration it tries to find an image in the directory `/small/logos` with a name that matches the supplied `ID-parameter`, if it doesn't exist it refers to `@gen_script`, that one leads to an `index.php` which will generate the image. This works without a problem.

Now for the part that is *giving me trouble*, the second kind of image the server is supposed to serve is *generally larger* and is created based on multiple parameters `(height, width, that sort of thing)`.

These images are *identifiable by a generated hash* which is always `128 characters long`.

What I'm trying to achieve is that the first three characters of the hash are turned into directories of the path where the image can be found, followed by the *complete hash and ".jpg"*. Here is the configuration for that aspect, *it's not working* and I'm out of ideas as to why:

```
location ~* "^\/image\.php\?hash=(?<a>.{1})(?<b>.{1})(?<c>.{1})(?<d>.{125})(?:.+)$" {
  try_files /images/$a/$b/$c/$a$b$c$d.jpg @image_gen;
}
location @image_gen {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /image.php$is_args$args;
}
```

In contrast to expected behaviour every request to `image.php` is actually received by (or sent to) `image.php`, creating the requested image again, *completely in contrast with what the (or any...) caching server is supposed to do*.

For clarification purposes, if the hash would be `abcde12345` (shortened for readability) then the image would be located in `/images/a/b/c/abcde12345.jpg`.
How can I ensure `try_files` checks if the file exists in the expected subdirectory-structure and if it doesn't then forward the original request to `/image.php` with its arguments, ensuring the image is generated?

Comment: You cannot test the args in the `location` expression. The `location` and `rewrite` directives use a normalized URI which does not include the `?` and anything following it.

Comment: @RichardSmith That makes sense, a parameter is not a location. If i change the `location ~* ...` to `location = /image.php`, can I regex the `$arg_hash` in an `if` statement within the location block? Or should it be another way?

Comment: You could use an `if`, but then you would not be able to use `try_files`. Are you stuck with the `/image.php?hash=` style of request?

Comment: Yes, afraid so, this is mostly intended as a drop-in replacement for an existing image caching server, what's new in this 'version' is the whole subdirectory placement of the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like below

```
http {

    map $arg_hash $arg_hash_folder {

        default '';
        ~*(.)(.)(.)(.*)$ /$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg;
    }

    server {

        location = /image.php {

            try_files $arg_hash_folder @process_image;
        }

        location @process_image {

            # Try rewrite here and see if it works
            # If it doesn't work then you should have the php processing code here
            # fastcgi_pass ....;
        }
    }
}
```

The map will give you the folder path, if it is not found the `process_image` will be called, here you can try a rewrite, which I have my doubts will work, so you will need to include the PHP processing code here again